# Clients with at least one call per vendor

Tags: postgresql-8.4

I have this situation.
I have clients and i have calls
I want yo know if a clien had at least 1 call per date , and if he/she not , i want an array with de dates without call.

client
id name
1  robert
2   nidia

Call
id date       id_client
1  2015-01-01     2
2  2015-01-31     1

The id client 1 has not calls all days least 2015-01-01

did you understand?

Comment: I think so. But what are you expecting from SO? An answer with a complete algorithm inc documentation?

Comment: Ey! Why de Agression?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, there's going to have to be some mechanism for determining exactly *which* dates your query checks against. There are theoretically an infinite number of dates during which a given client may *not* have placed any call! You have to query against a subset of that infinity.

If you're ok with hard-coding in the query a small number of dates to check, then I think this is what you're looking for:

```
drop table if exists call;
drop table if exists client;

create table client (id int, name varchar(32), primary key (id) );
insert into client (id,name) values (1,'robert'), (2,'nidia');

create table call (id int, d date, client_id int references client(id), primary key (id) );
insert into call (id,d,client_id) values (1,'2015-01-01',(select id from client where name='nidia')), (2,'2015-01-31',(select id from client where name='robert'));

select
    cl.name,
    array_agg(ds.d) no_call_dates
from
    client cl
    cross join (select '2015-01-01'::date d union all select '2015-01-15' union all select '2015-01-31') ds
    left join call ca on ca.client_id=cl.id and ca.d=ds.d
where
    ca.id is null
group by
    cl.name
;
```

Output:

```
  name  |      no_call_dates
--------+-------------------------
 nidia  | {2015-01-31,2015-01-15}
 robert | {2015-01-15,2015-01-01}
(2 rows)
```

I've hard-coded and unioned three dates into a single-column "table literal" (if you will) and cross-joined that with the `client` table, resulting in one row per-client-per-date. That result-set can then be left-joined with the `call` table on the client id and call date. You can then use the `where` clause to filter for only rows where the `call` table failed to join, which produces a result-set of no-call-days, still per-client-per-date. You can then group by the client and use the `array_agg()` aggregate function to construct the array of the dates on which the client did *not* have a call.

If you don't want to hard-code the dates, you can prepare a table of dates in advance and select from that in the `cross join` clause, or select all dates that are defined in the `call` table (`select distinct d from call;`), or use some more complex bit of logic to select the dates to check against. In all these cases, you would simply replace the "table literal" with the appropriate subquery.

**Edit:** Yes, that's very doable. You can use the [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-srf.html) function to generate an integer series and add it to a fixed start date, which results in a date range. This can be done in the cross-join subquery, as I mentioned before. A good approach to avoid repetition is to use a CTE to set the start and end date:

```
select
    cl.name,
    array_agg(ds.d order by ds.d) no_call_dates
from
    client cl
    cross join (with dr as (select '2015-01-01'::date s, '2015-01-31'::date e) select s+generate_series(0,e-s,15) d from dr) ds
    left join call ca on ca.client_id=cl.id and ca.d=ds.d
where
    ca.id is null
group by
    cl.name
;
```

Output:

```
  name  |      no_call_dates
--------+-------------------------
 nidia  | {2015-01-16,2015-01-31}
 robert | {2015-01-01,2015-01-16}
(2 rows)
```

In the above query, I generate three dates, 2015-01-01, 2015-01-16, and 2015-01-31, by using a date range from Jan 1 to Jan 31 with an increment of 15. Obviously for your case you'll probably want an increment of one, but I just used 15 for a nice simple example with only three dates.

Also, I added an `order by` clause in the `array_agg()` call, because it's nicer to get it ordered by date, rather than random.

Comment: Thanks Slowly i think im going to the solution. Do you know how i can create a virtual table of dates and join de dates of no calls? in this way:  Betweenn 2 dates?